# Как отлеживать нажатие левой кнопки мыши в консольном приложении C#?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно что бы после нажатия левой кнопки выполнялось какое либо действие до отжатия мыши, как я могу это cделать?
Пробовал такой способ:

```
public static System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState LeftButton { get; }
static void Main()
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        UpdateSampleResults("Left Button Pressed");
}
```

Выдает ошибку: System.InvalidOperationException: "Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA, поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов UI."

Comment: я предлагаю отталкиваться от цели приложения. Зачем консольному приложению знать о нажатии ЛКМ, курсоре и пр. ?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, подобное я делал в С++, я там в консоль вместо лога выводил, какие клавиши нажимаются, и это очень тормозило приложение

Comment: Вы используете .net framework или .net core?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На самом деле, задача для консоли не типичная, и следовательно .NET никак не помогает с решением. То есть готового решения от Microsoft нет, или я его не нашел.

Идея с использованием `System.Windows.Input` никуда не приведет, потому что вам придется реализовать Windows Message Loop, то есть фактически стартовать GUI приложение с окном, пусть даже не видимым, которое будет принимать сообщения от системы о нажатиях на мышь и клавиатуру. Альтернатива - крутить в цикле проверки нажатий, что выглядит еще хуже как лишняя нагрузка на систему. То есть ваше приложение ничего не делает, но при этом N раз в секунду крутит цикл, чтобы унюхать нажатия на мышь. Следующая проблема - координаты мыши, в `Windows.Input` там будут пиксели, а если окна нет, то пиксели чего? Задача еще усложнится. То есть даже если с помощью инструментов GUI приложения оно и решаемо, то очень далеко не просто это сделать. Гораздо проще выкинуть консоль и сделать сразу полноценное Windows приложение, например WPF.

Если же оставаться в консоли, то можно использовать P/Invoke методы Windows API, то есть низком уровне стучаться в систему и спрашивать, что же пользователь там делает с мышью у нас в окне. Так и поступим, потому что это как минимум проще, чем то что было предложено вами.

Сейчас будет много кода.

**NativeMethods.cs** - подключение методов Win API

```cs
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(ConsoleInputHandle nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleInput, ref ConsoleMode lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleInput, ConsoleMode dwMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool ReadConsoleInput(IntPtr hConsoleInput, [Out] InputRecord[] lpBuffer, int nLength, ref int lpNumberOfEventsRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool WriteConsoleInput(IntPtr hConsoleInput, InputRecord[] lpBuffer, int nLength, ref int lpNumberOfEventsWritten);
}
```

И чтобы с этой кучкой методов можно было работать, потребуются следующие энумераторы и структуры

**ConsoleStructs.cs**

```cs
[Flags]
public enum ConsoleMode : uint
{
    None = 0x0000,
    EchoInput = 0x0004,
    WindowInput = 0x0008,
    MouseInput = 0x0010,
    QuickEditMode = 0x0040,
    ExtendedFlags = 0x0080,
}

public enum ConsoleInputHandle : int
{
    StandardInput = -10,
    StandardOutput = -11,
    StandardError = -12
}

public struct ConsolePoint
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;
}

[Flags]
public enum ConsoleEventType : ushort
{
    Keyboard = 0x0001,
    Mouse = 0x0002,
    WindowBufferSize = 0x0004,
    Menu = 0x0008,
    Focus = 0x0010
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct InputRecord
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ConsoleEventType EventType;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public KeyboardRecord KeyEvent;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public MouseRecord MouseEvent;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public WindowBufferSizeRecord WindowBufferSizeEvent;
}

[Flags]
public enum MouseButtonState : uint
{
    NoButton = 0x0000,
    LeftButton = 0x0001,
    RightButton = 0x0002,
    MiddleButton = 0x0004,
    ThirdButton = 0x0008,
    FourthButton = 0x0010
}

[Flags]
public enum ControlKeyState : uint
{
    None = 0x0000,
    RightAlt = 0x0001,
    LeftAlt = 0x0002,
    RightCtrl = 0x0004,
    LeftCtrl = 0x0008,
    Shift = 0x0010,
    NumLock = 0x0020,
    ScrollLock = 0x0040,
    CapsLock = 0x0080,
    EnhancedKey = 0x0100,
}

[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlagsState : uint
{
    Idle = 0x0000,
    Move = 0x0001,
    DoubleClick = 0x0002,
    Wheel = 0x0004,
    HorizontalWheel = 0x0008
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MouseRecord
{
    public ConsolePoint Position;
    public MouseButtonState ButtonState;
    public ControlKeyState ControlKeyState;
    public MouseEventFlagsState EventFlags;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct KeyboardRecord
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public bool KeyDown;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public ushort RepeatCount;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ushort VirtualKeyCode;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public ushort VirtualScanCode;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public char UnicodeChar;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public byte AsciiChar;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public ControlKeyState ControlKeyState;

    public ConsoleKey ConsoleKey => (ConsoleKey)VirtualKeyCode;
}

public struct WindowBufferSizeRecord
{
    public ConsolePoint Size;
}
```

Я не сам с нуля это писал, но существенно переписал то что нашел на просторах англоязычного StackOverflow.

Собственно, вот сам класс, работающий с мышью и клавиатурой, подходящий под ваши задачи.

**ConsoleInputHandler.cs**

```cs
public class ConsoleInputHandler : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public Task Task { get; private set; }

    public delegate void ConsoleMouseEvent(MouseRecord r);
    public delegate void ConsoleKeyEvent(KeyboardRecord r);
    public delegate void ConsoleWindowBufferSizeEvent(WindowBufferSizeRecord r);

    public event ConsoleMouseEvent MouseEvent;
    public event ConsoleKeyEvent KeyEvent;
    public event ConsoleWindowBufferSizeEvent WindowBufferSizeEvent;

    public ConsoleInputHandler()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        IntPtr handle = NativeMethods.GetStdHandle(ConsoleInputHandle.StandardInput);
        InputRecord[] inputBuffer = new InputRecord[10];
        Task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (NativeMethods.ReadConsoleInput(handle, inputBuffer, inputBuffer.Length, ref numRead))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++)
                    {
                        switch (inputBuffer[i].EventType)
                        {
                            case ConsoleEventType.Mouse:
                                MouseEvent?.Invoke(inputBuffer[i].MouseEvent);
                                break;
                            case ConsoleEventType.Keyboard:
                                KeyEvent?.Invoke(inputBuffer[i].KeyEvent);
                                break;
                            case ConsoleEventType.WindowBufferSize:
                                WindowBufferSizeEvent?.Invoke(inputBuffer[i].WindowBufferSizeEvent);
                                break;
                            case ConsoleEventType.Menu:
                            case ConsoleEventType.Focus:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }

    private bool disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(ConsoleInputHandler));

        if (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            _cts.Cancel();

        if (disposing)
        {
            Task.Wait();
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~ConsoleInputHandler() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Вот, собственно и всё с хитрым кодом. Есть один нюанс, если вы запустите чтение ввода с помощью выше упомянутого класса с одновременным ожиданием `Console.ReadKey()`, то работать будет плохо, я сам долго не мог понять, почему не работает как надо, поэтому условие выхода из консольного приложения я унес в обработчик нажатий клавиш, а само ожидание сделал асинхронным "пока не остановится сам класс `ConsoleInputHandler`". Второй нюанс - чтобы работать с мышью в консоли, надо отрубить "быстрое выделение" этой мышью в консоли, этим занимается ниже приведенный метод `SetupConsole()`.

**Program.cs**

```cs
class Program
{
    private static ConsoleInputHandler inputHandler;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetupConsole();
        using (inputHandler = new ConsoleInputHandler())
        {
            inputHandler.MouseEvent += ConsoleInputHandler_MouseEvent;
            inputHandler.KeyEvent += ConsoleInputHandler_KeyEvent;
            await inputHandler.Task;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exited.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ConsoleInputHandler_KeyEvent(KeyboardRecord r)
    {
        if (r.KeyDown && r.ConsoleKey == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            inputHandler.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            int width = Console.BufferWidth - 1;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine($"KeyDown: {r.KeyDown}".PadRight(width));
            Console.WriteLine($"KeyChar: {r.UnicodeChar}, ConsoleKey: {r.ConsoleKey}".PadRight(width));
            Console.WriteLine($"RepeatCount: {r.RepeatCount}".PadRight(width));
            Console.WriteLine($"Controls: {r.ControlKeyState}".PadRight(width));
        }
    }

    private static void ConsoleInputHandler_MouseEvent(MouseRecord r)
    {
        int width = Console.BufferWidth - 1;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Position: {r.Position.X}, {r.Position.Y}".PadRight(width));
        Console.WriteLine($"Buttons: {r.ButtonState}".PadRight(width));
        Console.WriteLine($"Flags: {r.EventFlags}".PadRight(width));
        Console.WriteLine($"Controls: {r.ControlKeyState}".PadRight(width));
    }

    private static void SetupConsole()
    {
        IntPtr handle = NativeMethods.GetStdHandle(ConsoleInputHandle.StandardInput);
        ConsoleMode mode = default;
        NativeMethods.GetConsoleMode(handle, ref mode);
        mode &= ~ConsoleMode.QuickEditMode;
        NativeMethods.SetConsoleMode(handle, mode);
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль будет такой, будет интерактивно показывать, куда едет мышь и что нажимается на клавиатуре.

```
Position: 39, 14
Buttons: LeftButton
Flags: Move
Controls: None
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что _cts.Cancel() в ConsoleListener_KeyEvent пытается дождаться выполнения всех запланированных обратных вызовов на CancellationToken. Когда он используется с await Task.Delay, в качестве обратного вызова на нем запланирован хвост асинхронного метода. Если этот хвост вызывает Task.Wait, оба будут ждать вечно. Логичное решение - уйти в фоновый поток: `Task.Run(() => _cts.Cancel());_cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();`, но это можно реализовать проще, см. ответ.

Comment: Вот более подробное описание, почему происходит дедлок: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31496425/8674428

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и правда теперь работает, вот ни за что бы не подумал про эти обратные вызовы, буду знать. Про переусложнение понял, чуть-чуть переписал в сторону упрощения, но асинхронность оставил. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

Ответ aepot правильный, но он слишком переусложнен (в первой редакции) и это можно реализовать проще. Здесь асинхронный код вообще не нужен, без него проблемы дедлока не будет и можно дождаться завершения через WaitHandle.WaitOne:

```
public class ConsoleInputHandler : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void ConsoleMouseEvent(MouseRecord r);
    public delegate void ConsoleKeyEvent(KeyboardRecord r);
    public delegate void ConsoleWindowBufferSizeEvent(WindowBufferSizeRecord r);

    public event ConsoleMouseEvent MouseEvent;

    public event ConsoleKeyEvent KeyEvent;

    public event ConsoleWindowBufferSizeEvent WindowBufferSizeEvent;

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public ConsoleInputHandler()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        IntPtr handle = NativeMethods.GetStdHandle(ConsoleInputHandle.StandardInput);
        InputRecord[] inputBuffer = new InputRecord[10];
        CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (NativeMethods.ReadConsoleInput(handle, inputBuffer, inputBuffer.Length, ref numRead))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++)
                {
                    switch (inputBuffer[i].EventType)
                    {
                        case ConsoleEventType.Mouse:
                            MouseEvent?.Invoke(inputBuffer[i].MouseEvent);
                            break;
                        case ConsoleEventType.Keyboard:
                            KeyEvent?.Invoke(inputBuffer[i].KeyEvent);
                            break;
                        case ConsoleEventType.WindowBufferSize:
                            WindowBufferSizeEvent?.Invoke(inputBuffer[i].WindowBufferSizeEvent);
                            break;
                        case ConsoleEventType.Menu:
                        case ConsoleEventType.Focus:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(ConsoleInputHandler));

        if (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested) _cts.Cancel();

        _cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    private bool disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(ConsoleInputHandler));

        if (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }

        _cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();

        if (disposing)
        {
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~ConsoleInputHandler() => Dispose(false);
}

class Program
{
    static ConsoleInputHandler inputHandler;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetupConsole();
        using (inputHandler = new ConsoleInputHandler())
        {
            inputHandler.MouseEvent += ConsoleListener_MouseEvent;
            inputHandler.KeyEvent += ConsoleListener_KeyEvent;
            inputHandler.Run();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exited.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ConsoleListener_KeyEvent(KeyboardRecord r)
    {
        if (r.KeyDown && r.VirtualKeyCode == (ushort)ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            inputHandler.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            int width = Console.BufferWidth - 1;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine($"KeyDown: {r.KeyDown}".PadRight(width));
            Console.WriteLine($"KeyChar: {r.UnicodeChar}, ConsoleKey: {(ConsoleKey)r.VirtualKeyCode}".PadRight(width));
            Console.WriteLine($"RepeatCount: {r.RepeatCount}".PadRight(width));
            Console.WriteLine($"Controls: {r.ControlKeyState}".PadRight(width));
        }
    }

    private static void SetupConsole()
    {
        IntPtr handle = NativeMethods.GetStdHandle(ConsoleInputHandle.StandardInput);
        ConsoleMode mode = 0;
        NativeMethods.GetConsoleMode(handle, ref mode);
        mode &= ~ConsoleMode.QuickEditMode;
        NativeMethods.SetConsoleMode(handle, mode);
    }

    private static void ConsoleListener_MouseEvent(MouseRecord r)
    {
        int width = Console.BufferWidth - 1;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Position: {r.Position.X}, {r.Position.Y}".PadRight(width));
        Console.WriteLine($"Buttons: {r.ButtonState}".PadRight(width));
        Console.WriteLine($"Flags: {r.EventFlags}".PadRight(width));
        Console.WriteLine($"Controls: {r.ControlKeyState}".PadRight(width));
    }
}
```