# Постоянная проверка на нажатие клавишь

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Хотелось сделать CLI прогу которая все время проверяет ни нажата ли какая нибудь кнопка.

Я понимаю что можно просто сделать так:

```
while (true)
{
    if(Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Key.A)) 
    {
         //....
    {
}
```

Но нету ли более гуманного способа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-простому как-то так это делается.

```
private static void ReadingLoop()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    while ((keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        switch (keyInfo.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.A:
                // код, который выполняется при нажатии на кнопку
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task loop = Task.Run(() => ReadingLoop());

    // ... какой-то код, который можно выполнять, пока в цикле читается клава

    await loop; // подождать завершения
    Console.WriteLine("Bye.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[Или вот более продвинутое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201951/373567).