# Ввод данных и вывод в разных потоках C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность

Хочу написать змейку в консоли, и реализовать это следующим способом: существуют два потока: один принимает ввод с клавиатуры, второй - отрисовывает игру и делает какие-то проверки. Первый поток будет принимать ввод и записывать нажатые символы в поток команд, а второй поток будет считывать данные из этого буфера и реализовывать эти команды.
Не могу понять, как запустить эти две задачи в разных потоках (ранее не сталкивался с конкурентностью в C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу сразу перечисление, которое будет использовать во всех примерах.

```cs
public enum Direction
{
    Right,
    Down,
    Left,
    Up,
    Stop
}
```

Для начала, вашу задачу можно реализовать вообще без дополнительных потоков. Есть конечно кое-какие ограничения, связанные с этим, но для начала этот способ является наиболее предпочтительным, если вы только начинаете учиться писать код.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKey key = default;
        Direction direction = Direction.Right;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Down;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Up;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Right;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Left;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    direction = Direction.Stop;
                    break;
            }
            if (direction == Direction.Stop)
                break;

            Console.WriteLine(direction);
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно, вот весь движок для змейки готов. Вместо `Console.WriteLine(direction)` делаете вызов своего метода выполенния обновления игровой логики, передавая ему тот же `direction`, и готово.

Теперь многопоточные варианты. Многопоточность в C# давно развивается, начну с самого древнего способа делать потоки.

```cs
class Program
{
    private static Direction direction = Direction.Right;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Loop);
        thread.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Down;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Up;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Right;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Left;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    direction = Direction.Stop;
                    break;
            }
            if (direction == Direction.Stop)
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exit program");
    }

    private static void Loop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (direction == Direction.Stop)
                break;
            Console.WriteLine(direction);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exit thread");
    }
}
```

Работает точно так же, как и первый пример. Обратите внимание, что при нажатии `Esc` сначала в консоль напишется `Exit program`, и только потом `Exit thread`. Это не создает проблем, пока поток не является фоновым `Thread.IsBackground = true`, так как приложение при выходе убивает только фоновые потоки. Основные потоки должны завершиться самостоятельно, иначе приложение не завершится. Подводный камень здесь именно как раз в том, что приложение может зависнуть в процессах системы, пока вы его не убьете, если хотя-бы один основной поток не будет нормально завершен.

Кстати, потоки можно запускать более современным способ используя пул потоков. За это отвечает класс `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.

То есть строчки

```cs
Thread thread = new Thread(Loop);
thread.Start();
```

Можно заменить на просто

```cs
Task.Run(() => Loop());
```

Но все потоки из пула являются фоновыми, то есть при выходе из приложения ожидания завершения фонового потока не произойдет, он будет просто убит, а это еще одна проблема. Нам ведь хочется, чтобы весь наш код нормально завершался. Другими словами `Task.Run` здесь только усугубляет ситуацию.

Сразу отмечу разницу между первым и вторым примером. Второй пример - **неправильный**. Дело в том, что цикл чтения с клавиатуры не закончится, пока не нажмете Esc. А если вы закроете окно консоли, то в окне Output в Visual Studio, получите вот такой вывод.

```
The program '[5712] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Это означает, что приложение завершилось принудительно `Ctrl+C Exit`. При нормальном завершении приложения эта строчка выглядит так.

```
The program '[8224] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Но эту ошибку не побороть (во всяком случае, на данный момент, я не знаю как), можно побороть только проблему ненормального выхода из приложения. То есть сделать так, чтобы `Main` успел завершиться полностью прежде чем приложения закроется.

То есть надо возвращаться к способу, который использует `Console.KeyAvailable`. В противном случае `Console.ReadKey` будет "висеть" до тех пор, пока не будет нажата клавиша, и эту проблему без постоянного опрашивания `Console.KeyAvailable` в консоли [объехать не просто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201951/373567). А как выше было показано, дополнительный поток при таком подходе не нужен.

Возвращаемя к тому, с чего начали, только теперь делаем нормальное завершение приложения при закрытии окна консоли. Чтобы отслеживать что код приложения завершился я буду использовать вывод в отладочную консоль Visual Studio. Такую возможность дает специальный класс `Debug`.

Подключим пространство имен

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Получится вот такой код

```cs
class Program
{
    private static Direction direction = Direction.Right;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        ConsoleKey key = default;
        
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Down;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Up;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Right;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    direction = Direction.Left;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    direction = Direction.Stop;
                    break;
            }
            if (direction == Direction.Stop)
                break;

            Console.WriteLine(direction);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Program exit");
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        direction = Direction.Stop;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Вывод в окно `Output` Visual Studio теперь выглядит так

```
Program exit
The program '[5188] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

То есть приложение завершается нормально. Но есть проблема, обратите внимание на `Thread.Sleep`, который я использую чтобы дождаться завершения работы основного потока метода `Main`. Дело в том, что `Thread.Sleep`, как и `Console.ReadKey` просто так не прервать. Все это выливается в то, что окно приложения закрывается с задержкой в 1 секунду. Это некрасиво и выглядит как подвисание приложния. К счастью, этого можно избежать.

Есть удобная альтернатива `Thread.Sleep`, которую можно прерывать - `Task.Delay` (с помощью `CancellationToken`). Но `Task.Delay` асинхронный, следоательно здесь начинается асинхронное программирование с использование ключевых слов `async/await`. С самого начала поста я вас вел именно к этому.

```cs
class Program
{
    private static Direction direction = Direction.Right;
    private static readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        ConsoleKey key = default;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    while (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                    }
                }
                switch (key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        direction = Direction.Down;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        direction = Direction.Up;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        direction = Direction.Right;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        direction = Direction.Left;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        direction = Direction.Stop;
                        break;
                }
                if (direction == Direction.Stop)
                    break;

                Console.WriteLine(direction);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        Debug.WriteLine("Program exit");
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Теперь окно закрывается немедленно, при этом надпись в отладочкном окне `Program exit` все еще присутствует. С принудительным завершением приложения системой разобрались.

Теперь, как я писал [в примере для WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), хочется, чтобы Змейка реагировала на нажатия клавиш немедленно, а не с задержкой до секунды. Для этого опрос клавиатуры надо делать чаще, а не раз в секунду. Например 10 раз в секунду, при этом хочется, чтобы змейка так же двигалась раз в секунду, или с любой другой нужной скоростью, которая не зависит от частоты опроса клавиатуры. Вот здесь асинхронность разворачивается на полную и показывает свою суть.

```cs
class Program
{
    private static Direction direction = Direction.Right;
    private static readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private const int speedDelay = 1000;
    private static bool addDelay;

    private static Direction Direction
    {
        get => direction;
        set
        {
            if (value != direction)
            {
                direction = value;
                addDelay = true;
                Update();
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        ConsoleKey key = default;
        Task snakeTask = SnakeLoop(cts.Token);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100, cts.Token);
                while (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                }
                
                switch (key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        Direction = Direction.Down;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        Direction = Direction.Up;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        Direction = Direction.Right;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        Direction = Direction.Left;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        Direction = Direction.Stop;
                        break;
                }
                if (Direction == Direction.Stop)
                    break;
            }
            cts.Cancel();
            await snakeTask;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        Debug.WriteLine("Program exit");
    }

    private static async Task SnakeLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(speedDelay, token);
            if (addDelay)
            {
                addDelay = false;
                await Task.Delay(speedDelay / 2, token);
            }
            Update();
        }
    }

    private static void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Direction);
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Вот теперь получется то что нужно. Движок что надо. Не спорю, можно сделать еще лучше, так чтобы после нажатии на кнопку следующая итерация движения происходила ровно через `speedDelay`, это бы сделало поведение змейки плавнее.

Кстати, добавил свойство `Direction`, оно как раз содержит логику немедленной реакции на нажатие клавиши.

Все что вам осталось сделать - это реализовать метод `Update()`. Еще что сдесь не сделано - нет запрета на обратный ход. То есть если змейка ползла вниз, должно быть нельзя сразу же ползти вверх, то же самое для влево и вправо. Реализуйте это сами или подсмотрите в примере для WPF, ссылку на который я дал выше.

Кстати, в обработчике события `CurrentDomain_ProcessExit` вы можете сделать что-то полезное. Например записать количество набранных игроком очков на диск или вообще сохранить полное состояние игры, чтобы после перезапуска приложения все началось с того же места, на котором приложение было закрыто ранее.

Да, кстати, почитайте вот это - [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Maximilian Horton - я хочу написать змейку в консоли с использованием потоков..., aepot - ДЕРЖИТЕ МЕНЯ СЕМЕРО!!!