# Событие изменения окна в .Net core (windows, linux etc)

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net, asp.net-core

Хочу написать программу в консоли, интерфейс, которой подстраивался бы под размеры окна консоли. Не могу найти способ отслеживать изменение размера окна, чтобы перерисовывать вывод. Важно чтобы способ работал и на винде и на линуксе. Нужна помощь! ^_^

Comment: вы конечно можете извращаться, но просто надо понимать, что консоль  - она не для интерфейса сделана. Хотите интерфейс - пилите соотвествующее прилоение на формах или WPF или что там сейчас модно.

Comment: достаточно зайти на гитхаб и немного поискать.... https://github.com/Haydend/ConsoleDraw или https://github.com/TomaszRewak/C-sharp-console-gui-framework

Comment: Фоновый поток, который считывает в цикле параметры окна.

Comment: При чем здесь ASP.NET Core, если речь про консоль?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34208406/12888024, совет выше про крутить в цикле проверку размера не поддерживаю, мне кажется это костыльным способом. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201951/373567) есть решение, но только для винды. Для линуксы наверняка тоже подобное существует. Базовой поддержки события изменения размера окна консоли в дотнете нет. Его [собирались добавить](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/19533), но передумали из-за низкой популярности проблемы, с чем я в принципе согласен.