# Мне надо получить ввод с гейпада в консоли C#

Tags: c#

Я гуглил на русском и английском но ничего не нашёл кроме пакета SharpDX.DirectInput но получение ввода я так и не сумел сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Хихикнул с "гейпада" :)

Comment: Если геймпад симулирует нажатия клавы или движение мыши, то гляньте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201951/373567