# Как написать событие на клик мыши по консоли

Tags: c#

Задача написать событие, которое будет выполняться при каждом щелчке мыши по любой области консоли, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C# нельзя написать событие на клик мыши в консоли напрямую, так как консольное приложение не имеет пользовательского интерфейса, на котором можно кликать мышью.

Однако, вы можете использовать API Windows Console, чтобы обработать событие мыши в консоли. Для этого нужно:

Импортировать функцию SetConsoleMode из библиотеки kernel32.dll.
Использовать SetConsoleMode для установки режима ввода консоли, включающего обработку событий мыши.
Ожидать события мыши с помощью функции ReadConsoleInput.
Обрабатывать полученное событие мыши и выполнять нужные действия.

Comment: Благодарю вас, благодаря вам удалось найти пост на эту тему.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201765/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-c